# how is a website certificate file cryptographically readable by windows?

Tags: ssl-certificate, public-key, cryptography

I have a .crt file signed by a CA. I `cat` the file to see that it is ascii text. Yet when I double click on the .crt file in windows, it opens it up and somehow displays all the information that's inside of it. Is windows automatically trying all of it's known CA public keys until finding the one that can translate that .crt file into information? How can I manually unencrypt the certificate to view the information (preferably in linux commands since I know those better)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ASCII characters you see are an ASCII-encoded certificate, according to the SSL standards.  There are a number of tools you can use to decode (rather than decrypt) the certificate; here's an example:

```
[me@anni tmp]$ cat /tmp/cert
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIFNDCCBBygAwIBAgIDB9RMMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAMDwxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVT
[many lines deleted to save space]
n0lvNATb6/RC7CmSMw5RelfVqm19YorWPeQ8c/a6uHSgYhLboPeNTA==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
[me@anni tmp]$ openssl x509 -text -noout -in /tmp/cert
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number: 513100 (0x7d44c)
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=US, O=GeoTrust, Inc., CN=RapidSSL CA
        Validity
            Not Before: Aug 16 06:07:05 2012 GMT
            Not After : Oct 16 09:42:56 2016 GMT
        Subject: serialNumber=5VXPb8ozky-0FKC/YsTB4dvcoUwVakXy, OU=GT42621204, OU=See www.rapidssl.com/resources/cps (c)12, OU=Domain Control Validated - RapidSSL(R), CN=www.teaparty.net
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:aa:e2:fd:b3:a2:5c:fa:33:0b:fa:14:8a:3a:3d:
[...]
                    f8:01
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                keyid:6B:69:3D:6A:18:42:4A:DD:8F:02:65:39:FD:35:24:86:78:91:16:30

            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature, Key Encipherment
            X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
                TLS Web Server Authentication, TLS Web Client Authentication
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
                DNS:www.teaparty.net, DNS:teaparty.net
            X509v3 CRL Distribution Points: 

                Full Name:
                  URI:http://rapidssl-crl.geotrust.com/crls/rapidssl.crl

            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                1A:6D:59:8A:CD:C0:FD:AC:3C:D0:AF:C0:99:48:F5:5C:B9:AD:A9:E3
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:FALSE
            Authority Information Access: 
                OCSP - URI:http://rapidssl-ocsp.geotrust.com
                CA Issuers - URI:http://rapidssl-aia.geotrust.com/rapidssl.crt

            X509v3 Certificate Policies: 
                Policy: 2.16.840.1.113733.1.7.54
                  CPS: http://www.geotrust.com/resources/cps

    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
         28:30:d9:19:a8:5e:8e:56:f6:98:1c:e0:be:b3:39:6e:6f:4c:
[...]
         a0:f7:8d:4c
```

Answer (score 1):

Your .crt file is a X.509 standard certificate, stored in the binary ASN.1 DER format, encoded in Base64. Software that reads these certificates knows how to interpret all these formats and get to the information inside.